# Displaying different headers using IF-stament in WORDPRESS

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, header

guru's :D

I have a problem using IF-staments in my header.php file.

I'm using the wordpress platform. The code below should display different styles of headers, by checking which page the user is currently on.

My problem: when I call `get_header();` in any of the pages, I get all the code from the 
header.php file, it seems that the functions doesnt care about my IF-stament in 
header.php.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

The code below is my header.php file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">

<?php
$post_obj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
var_dump($slug);
?>

<?
if (is_page($slug == "student_info")) {
?>
<div id="header">

    <div class="header-content">
        <div class="link-1"> 
            <a href=""><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_activated_1.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="link-2"> 
            <a href="student_valg"><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_2.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="link-3"> 
            <a href="student_laeringsmaal"><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_3.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="link-4"> 
            <a href="student_status"><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_4.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="link-5"> 
            <a href="student_dagbog"><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_5.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="link-6"> 
            <a href="student_evaluering"><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_6.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<?
} elseif ($slug == "student_valg") {
?>
<div id="header">

    <div class="header-content">
        <div class="link-1"> 
            <a href="student_info"><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_1.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="link-2"> 
            <a href=""><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_activated_2.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="link-3"> 
            <a href="student_laeringsmaal"><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_3.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="link-4"> 
            <a href="student_status"><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_4.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="link-5"> 
            <a href="student_dagbog"><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_5.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="link-6"> 
            <a href="student_evaluering"><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_6.png'/> </a>   
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<?
} elseif ($slug == "student_laeringmaal") {
?>

<div id="header">

    <div class="header-content">
        <div class="link-1"> 
            <a href="student_info"><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_1.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="link-2"> 
            <a href="student_valg"><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_2.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="link-3"> 
            <a href=""><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_activated_3.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="link-4"> 
            <a href="student_status"><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_4.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="link-5"> 
            <a href="student_dagbog"><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_5.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="link-6"> 
            <a href="student_evaluering"><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_6.png'/> </a>   
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
<?
} elseif ($slug == "student_status") {
?>
<div id="header">

    <div class="header-content">
        <div class="link-1"> 
            <a href="student_info"><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_1.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="link-2"> 
            <a href="student_valg"><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_2.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="link-3"> 
            <a href="student_laeringsmaal"><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_3.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="link-4"> 
            <a href=""><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_activated_4.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="link-5"> 
            <a href="student_dagbog"><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_5.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="link-6"> 
            <a href="student_evaluering"><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_6.png'/> </a>   
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
<?
} elseif ($slug == "student_dagbog") {
?>
<div id="header">

    <div class="header-content">
        <div class="link-1"> 
            <a href="student_info"><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_1.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="link-2"> 
            <a href="student_valg"><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_2.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="link-3"> 
            <a href="student_laeringsmaal"><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_3.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="link-4"> 
            <a href="student_status"><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_4.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="link-5"> 
            <a href=""><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_activated_5.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="link-6"> 
            <a href="student_evaluering"><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_6.png'/> </a>   
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
<?
} else {
?>
<div id="header">

    <div class="header-content">
        <div class="link-1"> 
            <a href="student_info"><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_1.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="link-2"> 
            <a href="student_valg"><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_2.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="link-3"> 
            <a href="student_laeringsmaal"><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_3.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="link-4"> 
            <a href="student_status"><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_4.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="link-5"> 
            <a href="student_dagbog"><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_5.png'/> </a>   
        </div>
        <div class="link-6"> 
            <a href=""><img src='../wp-content/themes/tutorial_theme-child/images/proces_punkt_activated_6.png'/> </a>   
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
<?
}
?>
```

Comment: maybe you should use `<?php` instead of `<?` on your server. Short tags need to be enabled to make them work. Long Tags should always work.

Comment: when i change the <? to <?php before the first if-stament, i get this parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in 179 (the last ?>)

Comment: There is no error given in your question. Also it seems you don't understand which problem exactly you've got, and there is only one solution to that: Trouble shooting: Exit early, double check your expectations.

Comment: Hakre: if u can point in me in some direction of solving this in an other way, pls do! :)

Comment: you should change all `<?` to `<?php`. and I think `if (is_page($slug == "student_info")) {` is not what you want...

Comment: Sure: http://php.net/docs - And as this is a Wordpress support request: http://wordpress.org/support - And as this here is Stackoverflow: I am unable to reproduce what you ask about with the code you've posted in your question. The code looks incomplete/broken, it does not exectue as described in your question. *Please Note:* Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and **include valid code to reproduce it** — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

Comment: Ty steven. I'll try that. And hakre, i'll keep your guidance in my mind, when i post next time. ty.